# AngularJS simple ng-controller not working

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm beginner in angularJs and I have this simple and maybe stupid problem, can't connect simple controller to view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="SimpleController">
        NAME:
        <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="name" />
        <br/>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:name | orderBy:'city'">{{cust.name | uppercase}} - {{cust.city}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script src="js/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        function SimpleController($scope){
            $scope.customers=[{name:'Amelie',city:'Tbilisi'},{name:'Jani', city:'New York'}];
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

So, can anyone explain what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: You have the model name and the field name in object of equals, may be a problem with that. Change the name of the model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you didn't reference the angularjs script in your page.

Then depends on your Angular version (>= 1.3), you have to create a module and register the controller inside.

```js
angular.module("myApp",[])
.controller("SimpleController",function($scope){
    $scope.customers=[{name:'Amelie',city:'Tbilisi'},{name:'Jani', city:'New York'}];
});
```

```html
<html data-ng-app="myApp">
```

Comment: That worked for me. Angular version caused the problem, I was using old YouTube tutorial for learning. Thanks

Comment: Nice ! If this answer solved your problem, could you mark it as answered ?

Answer (score 2):

From angular vs`1.3.x` you have to bind controller with module in order to use.

Like this

```
angular
   .module("app",[])
   .controller("SimpleController",function($scope){
     $scope.customers=[{name:'Amelie',city:'Tbilisi'},{name:'Jani', city:'New York'}];
})
```

Add module name in html

```
<html ng-app="app">
```

<kbd>**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/ujnrrpek/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: It is not allowed by default, but it still allowed.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan thanks for mentioning :)